# How to recursively find child property attributes

Tags: c#, attributes

I have an attribute for validation called `Required() : BaseAttribute`, and I can track it using the following code: (The BaseAttribute just implements the IsValid() Method.)

```
public static String Validate(object Object)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    if (Object != null)
    {
        Type ObjectType = Object.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] Properties = ObjectType.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo Property in Properties)
        {
            object[] Attributes = Property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(BaseAttribute), true);
            foreach (object Attribute in Attributes)
                builder.AppendLine(((BaseAttribute)Attribute).IsValid(Property, Object));
        }
    }
return builder.ToString();
}
```

The problem is, this works:

```
class roh {
    [Required()]
    public string dah { get; set; }
}

class main {
    Console.WriteLine(Validate(new roh()));
}
```

but this doesn't:

```
class fus {
    private roh _roh
    public roh Roh {
        get { if (_roh == null)
                  _roh = new roh;
              return _roh; }
        set { _roh = value; }
    }
}

class roh {
    [Required()]
    public string Dah { get; set; }
}

class main {
    Console.WriteLine(Validate(new fus()));
}
```

How can I modify my Validate method so that it can recursively find the custom attributes no matter how deep the object is?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Microsoft Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx).  It has some build in validation blocks (similar in style to what you're using here) and does support recursive object validation down the object graph, I believe.

You reference the EntLib Validation DLL, and can either use the built-in validation or write your own.  You can then validate it using a simple `Validation.Validate(myObject)` call.

Hope that might help :)

Comment: Also.. Microsoft has a little thing called DataAnnotations which is part of the .NET 4.0 framework. Since he's doing validation using attributes, DataAnnotations is easier to start with.

Comment: @Steven EntLib supports exactly that use case, but more tools for the toolkit are always useful and welcome: post it as an answer.

Comment: I am very familar with VAB, and think is great (so great that [I've written almost a dozen articles about it](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/archive.php?c=Validation_Application_Block)). In that sense, we're on the same line. Too be honest, I don't like attribute based validation all that much, which is the only thing DataAnnotations can do. However, VAB is much more complex than DataAnnotations and for simple things I always advise DataAnnotations over VAB.

Answer (score 1):

You already said the magic word - recursion. For every property you visit, call Validate on the object it stores, and voila.

One caveat is infinite recursion - this will work OK if your object graph is a tree. If it's more complex, you'll need to track which objects you have already visited.